# The mobile chrome browser native share button copies only the url without query string when using Router from NextJS

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, next.js

I looked into this solution [history.pushState does not update url for "share ..." button on mobile Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518379/history-pushstate-does-not-update-url-for-share-button-on-mobile-chrome).

I tried this snippet,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:3000">
    <title>Test Website</title>
    <script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    Hey shan <br> <br>

    <button id="btn">Click me</button>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btn').click(function () {
                history.pushState({urlPath:'/'}, "/",  "/1234?name=shan&color=87878");
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is working even without changing canonical url too. With the above code if i click the native share button in android chrome browser the string `http://localhost:3000/1234?name=shan&color=87878` gets copied.

But in my actual website the same is not happening. The only change over there is `Router.replace` from nextjs. The approximate snippet looks like this

```
buttonClick = Router.replace(...)
```

The problem is when user clicks a button `Router.replace` is called with the params and everything works except the native share copies only the url `http://localhost:3000/1234` not the query string.

But the querystring gets copied when i use the copy button or edit button on the browser.

I am not sure how to approach this problem, what could be the issue? Is any meta tag could block copying the queryparam?

Comment: Try changing the canonical url  as per the post you mentioned and try once in mobile. It worked for me. But for some reason with the localhost code posted works and picks the querystring too even when we provided the canonical url. But with some actual site I modified and checked it takes the canonical url when provided else it takes the actual url. Did you tried in the actual site not with the localhost snippet you posted?

Comment: Yeah I tried that now, its working that way!